# Receive not define error message even known declared global value

Tags: python

```
def buy():
    while True:
        items={"Armor": 25, "Sword": 25}
        print("What do you want to buy?\n1/Armor +25 defense\t50 golds\n2/Sword +25 damage\t50 golds")
        s1=input("Choose the item you want to buy (1 and/or 2 only): ")
        try:
            global a
            a=int(s1)
            if a in range (1,3):
                break
        except ValueError:
            pass

buy()
print(a)
```

error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\code\work\The Role-Playing combat game.py", line 58, in <module>
    print(a) NameError: global name 'a' is not defined
```

Line 58 is print(a)

I declared "a" as the global value, but somehow the interpreter gives me the error message. Please help, thanks.
Solved, declare "a" outside of the function first

Comment: Please show us the actual error message.  Thanks.

Comment: and there is no error on my machine

Comment: Did you declare `a` earlier in the file?  e.g. before calling `global a`?

Comment: do you mean outside the function or inside? because if I declare it outside the function the value will not change

Comment: oops you're right, I have to declare it outside of the function first. Cant blame me too much homework today :D. Thanks a lot Remolten

Comment: Outside the function, before you call it.  By setting `a = whatever`.  You have to declare it before you call `global` on it.

Comment: It is a good idea to pull your answer out of the question and post an actual answer. Alternatively, @Remolten, you may want to post an actual answer instead of a comment.

Comment: OK answer posted.  Select as answer if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Did you declare the `a` variable earlier in your code?  Otherwise, calling global a before declaring it will throw that error.  You need to put `a = something` before you call `global a` on it.